# Mary couldn't (possibly) go to jail for the crime. - "possibly" necessary here to express future impossibility?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, could-modal

I came across this page that teaches "could." https://www.englishpage.com/modals/could.html

The below example is from the page. I wonder whether "possibly" is a necessary element here to express future impossibility; because you see, if it is not there, it is a little unclear whether you are talking about the past ability or future possibility. However, all this is my guess.
Can somebody shed some light on this?

**Example 1**

> Mary couldn't (possibly) go to jail for the crime.

Comment: I don't think so. *Possibly* is helpful to give context in a list which is all about the use of **could** in different tenses. But I can easily think of other ways of expressing the future tense. (*Mary has just been arrested and you say to me, "She couldn't go to jail, could she?"*)

Answer (score 1):

Your example has no context, being a made-up sentence in a list of made-up sentences. But if I imagine someone’s uttering the sentence in a real, natural conversation, the *possibly* would be included to emphasize the unbelievability of the idea. Along the lines of

> Really? Mary? Thrown in jail? That’s not gonna happen. There’s no **way** they could send her to jail for the crime. She was in Finland when it happened.